# How to populate String from html with list?

Tags: java

I have mail template with table.With two columns.One is names,second is something else .I want to replace string whose is posted on every row
"{names_list}" with names from my list.
When I do like this :

```
private String changeTextInHtml(String str){
    String s = "";
    for(int i=0;i<listOfNames().size();i++){
        s = StringUtils.replace(str, "{names_list}", listOfNames().get(i));
    }

        return s;
}
```

I am getting populated table but with only last name from the list.
In every row is that last name.
How to populate name,by name?
Method listOfNames() return that list.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] and explain the situation in more detail. It's currently **unclear** what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

- First of all the replace method (if is from apache.commons.lang)
  replaces all occurrences of pattern in string.
- The input string will not change

You must change the method as follow (I suppose that there is list of patterns in your HTML):

```
private String changeTextInHtml(String str) {
    String s = str;
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfNames().size(); i++) {
        s = StringUtils.replaceFirst(s, "{names_list}", listOfNames().get(i));
    }
    return s;
}
```

How ever it is better to use templates language such as [FreeMarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/)